# Text carousel doesn't work if I have more than 3 messages

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a very simple texte carousel with jQuery.

It looks working when I have 3 messages but not when I have 2 or more than 3.

How I can solve this ?

Also, how I can update the message number (1 of ?) ?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rm7ukmar/

```
$(function() {
    var quotes = $(".message");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showQuote(change) {
        quoteIndex += change;
        if (quoteIndex < 0) {
            quoteIndex += quotes.length;
        }
        else if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
            quoteIndex -= quotes.length;
        }
        quotes.stop(true, true).hide().eq(quoteIndex)
            .fadeIn(1)
            .delay(1)
            .fadeOut(1)
            .queue(function() { showQuote(1); });
    }  
    showQuote(1);

    $('#prev').on('click', function() {
        showQuote(-1);
    });

    $('#next').on('click', function() {
        showQuote(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count instead of `?` by using a span to bind the value over there and use `$('.sliderCount').text(quotes.length);` to bind the value.

```js
$(function() {
  var quotes = $(".message");
  var quoteIndex = -1;
  $('.sliderCount').text(quotes.length);

  function showQuote(change) {
    quoteIndex += change;
    if (quoteIndex < 0) {
      quoteIndex += quotes.length;
    } else if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
      quoteIndex -= quotes.length;
    }
    quotes.stop(true, true).hide().eq(quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(1)
      .delay(1000)
      .fadeOut(1)
      .queue(function() {
        showQuote(1);
      });
  }
  showQuote(1);

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(-1);
  });

  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="message">
      Message 1
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 2
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 3
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 4
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    1 of <span class="sliderCount"></span>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="prev">
          <</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="next">></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** Check below snippet to stop `autoplay`

```js
$(function() {
  var quotes = $(".message");
  var quoteIndex = -1;
  $('.sliderCount').text(quotes.length);

  function showQuote(change) {
    quoteIndex += change;
    if (quoteIndex < 0) {
      quoteIndex += quotes.length;
    } else if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
      quoteIndex -= quotes.length;
    }
    quotes.stop(true, true).hide().eq(quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(1)
      .delay(1000);
  }
  showQuote(1);

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(-1);
  });

  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="message">
      Message 1
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 2
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 3
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 4
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Message 5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    1 of <span class="sliderCount"></span>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="prev">
          <</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="next">></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It working for the `prev`and `next` buttons. But how I can stop the carousel from start ? I do not want it start automatically. Just on lick on `prev`and `next` buttons.

Comment: do you want to stop `autoplay`?

Comment: Yes please. Excuse my english.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.